# What is the sense of IE's blocking activex content on my C drive?

Tags: javascript, security, internet-explorer-9, activex, methodology

I have just tested (in 5 minutes) in Firefox and Chrome webpages on my C drive for uploading to my website. I have spent the past hour trying to test the same pages in IE9. By default, IE blocks the pages because there is a few lines of javascript. If I click the b"allow active content" warning, IE either hangs or allows active x content for 5 minutes, then hangs again. If I check "allow active x to run on my computer" in the advanced settings, it doesn't load the page at all, or claims the page is not found, or - once - warned me that script was too long. I just removed every darn script in my homepage, and all I've got now is a  blank screen.  I tried Microsoft for a solution and they give me this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537628.aspx
And it didn't make any difference.
Other advice includes editing the registry, playing with the security settings etc. etc.

This has been happening with IE as far as I remember, although once you could just click "allow" on a popup and it'd run the page. What is the reasoning? How come it's safe in Firefox and Chrome and IE blocks everything, especially since it's on my own frigging C drive?

Comment: There's no answerable question here, not with the information provided. If you edit to remove the ranting, and to quote the **minimum necessary code** to replicate the issue, people can probably help you.

Comment: If you're running from a local C drive, then yes, you will get content like this blocked by the browser. There's not much you can do about that; these security settings are there for your protection. If you want to test locally, at least make the effort to set up a localhost web server; that will give you a more realistic test environment. C drive is just not going to cut it. But the real question is what kind of activeX content is it, and why would you need in 2013 and in IE9?

Comment: ...it's just a few javascript bells and whistles (but IE always says it's ActiveX, whatever that is) and in IE9 because that's all I have on Windows 7 Home Premium Classic Gold edition. I have a simple li'l website and I loike to test the latest bell or whistle in mt

Comment: ...in Chrome, Firefox and IE9 8and of course Sauce Labs) before updating. So the question was (it was in the "question"): Why does IE9 continue with this nonsense if Chrome, FF and my Kaspersky antivirus firewall see no threat at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [underlying philosophy](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2011/02/28/activex-filtering-for-consumers.aspx) is as follows:

> “ActiveX” is the technology these plug-ins use to run inside of IE. Like other add-ons, they are essentially Windows applications that run in the browser. Poorly written add-ons and ActiveX controls can therefore affect IE’s performance, reliability, security and privacy in similar ways.